# Is C actually Turing-complete?

Tags: computability, turing-completeness, c

I was trying to explain to someone that C is Turing-complete, and realized that I don't actually know if it is, indeed, technically Turing-complete. (C as in the abstract semantics, not as in an actual implementation.)

The "obvious" answer (roughly: it can address an arbitrary amount of memory, so it can emulate a RAM machine, so it's Turing-complete) isn't actually correct, as far as I can tell, as although the C standard allows for size_t to be arbitrarily large, it must be fixed at some length, and no matter what length it is fixed at it is still finite. (In other words, although you could, given an arbitrary halting Turing machine, pick a length of size_t such that it will run "properly", there is no way to pick a length of size_t such that all halting Turing machines will run properly)

So: is C99 Turing-complete?

Comment: What are the "abstract semantics" of C? Are they defined anywhere?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus - See e.g. [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), i.e. C as defined in the standard as opposed to e.g. "this is how gcc does it".

Comment: there is the "technicality" that modern computers do not have infinite memory like the TM yet are still considered "universal computers". and note that programming languages in their "semantics" do not really assume a finite memory except that all their _implementations_ are of course limited in memory. see eg [does our pc work as a Turing machine](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11514/does-our-pc-work-as-turing-machine). anyway essentially _all_ "mainstream" programming languages are Turing complete.

Comment: C  (like Turing machines) isn't limited to using internal computer memory for its computations, so this really isn't a valid argument against the Turing completeness of C.

Comment: @reinierpost - that's like saying a teletype is sapient. That's saying that "C + an external TM-equivalent" is Turing-complete, not that C is Turing-complete.

Comment: @TLW: No, it isn't; but perhaps this is a better subject for chat.

Comment: If `#pragma` is allowed, an implementation can be Turing-complete trivially.

Comment: Does it make sense to think of a theoretical device such as a Turing Machine (that has unlimited resources and cannot exist) in terms of a concrete language (designed to be implementable) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Is Lisp a "concrete language", by your definition?

Comment: @tlw: it is both.

Comment: A term that I created: [a computation is Turing Complete] when its implementation language would otherwise be Turing Complete except for the lack of an unlimited tape and the lack of an unlimited tape has no effect on the computation. This would indicate than many computations done in "c" would be Turing complete computations.

Comment: @polcott - I don't quite understand that definition... lack of an unlimited tape (memory space? It's not obvious what "tape" would be for a language like C) does indeed have effects on computations done in C in some cases.

Comment: @TLW The simple fact that aTuring Machine has unlimited storage and every actual hardware machine does not have unlimited storage does not prevent the hardware machine from computing most of the things that a TM can compute.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think the answer is no, for rather subtle reasons. I [asked on Theoretical Computer Science a few years ago](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/maximum-computational-power-of-a-c-implementation) and didn't get an answer that goes beyond what I'll present here.

In most programming languages, you can simulate a Turing machine by:

- simulating the finite automaton with a program that uses a finite amount of memory;
- simulating the tape with a pair of linked lists of integers, representing the content of the tape before and after the current position. Moving the pointer means transferring the head of one of the lists onto the other list.

A concrete implementation running on a computer would run out of memory if the tape got too long, but an ideal implementation could execute the Turing machine program faithfully. This can be done with pen and paper, or by buying a computer with more memory, and a compiler targeting an architecture with more bits per word and so on if the program ever runs out of memory.

This doesn't work in C because it's impossible to have a linked list that can grow forever: there's always some limit on the number of nodes.

To explain why, I first need to explain what a C implementation is. C is actually a family of programming languages. The [ISO C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (more precisely, a specific version of this standard) defines (with the level of formality that English allows) the syntax and semantics a family of programming languages. C has a lot of *undefined behavior* and *implementation-defined behavior*. An “implementation” of C codifies all the implementation-defined behavior (the list of things to codify is in appendix J for C99). Each implementation of C is a separate programming language. Note that the meaning of the word “implementation” is a bit peculiar: what it really means is a language variant, there can be multiple different compiler programs that implement the same language variant.

In a given implementation of C, a byte has $2^{\texttt{CHAR_BIT}}$ possible values. All data can represented as an array of bytes: a type `t` has at most 
$2^{\texttt{CHAR_BIT} \times \texttt{sizeof(t)}}$ possible values. This number varies in different implementations of C, but for a given implementation of C, it's a constant.

In particular, pointers can only take at most $2^{\texttt{CHAR_BIT} \times \texttt{sizeof(void*)}}$ values. This means that there is a finite maximum number of addressable objects.

The values of `CHAR_BIT` and `sizeof(void*)` are observable, so if you run out of memory, you can't just resume running your program with larger values for those parameters. You would be running the program under a different programming language — a different C implementation.

If programs in a language can only have a bounded number of states, then the programming language is no more expressive than finite automata. The fragment of C that's restricted to addressable storage only allows at most $n \times 2^{\texttt{CHAR_BIT} \times \texttt{sizeof(void*)}}$ program states where $n$ is the size of the abstract syntax tree of the program (representing the state of the control flow), therefore this program can be simulated by a finite automaton with that many states. If C is more expressive, it has to be through the use of other features.

C does not directly impose a maximum recursion depth. An implementation is allowed to have a maximum, but it's also allowed not to have one. But how do we communicate between a function call and its parent? Arguments are no good if they're addressable, because that would indirectly limit the depth of recursion: if you have a function `int f(int x) { … f(…) …}` then all the occurrences of `x` on active frames of `f` have their own address and so the number of nested calls is bounded by the number of possible addresses for `x`.

A C program can use non-addressable storage in the form of `register` variables. “Normal” implementations can only have a small, finite number of variables that don't have an address, but in theory an implementation could allow an unbounded amount of `register` storage. In such an implementation, you can make an unbounded amount of recursive calls to a function, as long as its argument are `register`. But since the arguments are `register`, you can't make a pointer to them, and so you need to copy their data around explicitly: you can only pass around a finite amount of data, not an arbitrary-sized data structure that's made of pointers.

With unbounded recursion depth, and the restriction that a function can only get data from its direct caller (`register` arguments) and return data to its direct caller (the function return value), you get the power of **deterministic pushdown automata**.

I can't find a way to go further.

(Of course you could make the program store the tape content externally, through file input/output functions. But then you wouldn't be asking whether C is Turing-complete, but whether C plus an infinite storage system is Turing-complete, to which the answer is a boring “yes”. You might as well define the storage to be a Turing oracle — call `fopen("oracle", "r+")`, `fwrite` the initial tape content to it and `fread` back the final tape content.)

Comment: It is not immediately clear why the set of addresses should be finite. I wrote some thoughts in an answer to the question you link: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/37036/43393

Comment: Sorry, but by the same logic, there are no Turing-complete programming languages at all. Each language has an explicit or implicit limitation on address space. If you create a machine with infinite memory, then random access pointers will obviously also be of infinite length. Therefore, if such machine appears, it will have to offer an instruction set for sequential memory access, along with an API for high-level languages.

Comment: @IMil This is not true. Some programming languages have no limitation on address space, not even implicitly. To take an obvious example, a universal Turing machine where the initial state of the tape forms the program is a Turing-complete programming language. Many programming languages that are actually used in practice have the same property, for example Lisp and SML. A language doesn't have to have a concept of “random access pointer”. *(cont.)*

Comment: @IMil *(cont.)* Implementations usually do for performance, but we know that an implementation running on a particular computer is not Turing-complete since it's bounded by the size of the computer's memory. But that means that the implementation doesn't implement the whole language, only a subset (of programs running in N bytes of memory). You can run the program on a computer, and if it runs out of memory, move it to a bigger computer, and so on forever or until it halts. That would be a valid way to implement the whole language.

Comment: What practical difference in terms of computability is there between a machine with unlimited memory and a machine with very large memory?

Comment: @polcott No matter how much memory you have, sooner or later you'll find some application or data set that wants even more. A theoretical machine that has unlimited memory would not have this problem.

Comment: So in other words you are not aware of any defined category of computation that requires unlimited memory?

Comment: @polcott I don't understand what you mean by “defined category of computation”. An example of something a computer with finite memory can't do, but a computer with unlimited memory can do, is to simulates itself. [This answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32845/why-really-is-the-halting-problem-so-important/32862#32862) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I have a very excellent libx86emu x86 emulator that is running on an x86 platform taking a very tiny little fraction of total memory. https://github.com/wfeldt/libx86emu This is a machine that simulates itself and it does so in far less than 0.1% of its memory.

Comment: @polcott It can't emulate itself. It can only emulate a similar machine with less memory.

Comment: It emulates its own functionality perfectly and has 99.9% of the same memory.

Comment: For every computation C that is decidable on a Turing Machine M that is decidable on another machine N this other machine N is Turing complete for this computation C. (paraphrase of the first answer)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete 

Thus the "C" programming language and corresponding real world machines having finite memory are Turing Complete for every decidable computation that is also decidable by a Turing Machine.

Comment: @polcott, it makes no sense to speak about "practical" and "computability" in the same sentence.  Computability (and Turing-completeness) is not about what it is practical; it is about what is mathematically true.  You seem to want to talk about what holds "for all engineering purposes" but that's not what Turing-completeness is about.

Comment: C uses separate compilation. Different compiled units do not need to use the same values of `CHAR_BIT` or `sizeof(void *)`. (They do in practice, of course. But that is not a property of C, as far as I know.)

Comment: @reinierpost The value of `CHAR_BIT` is a constant in a given C implementation. So are `sizeof` values. The definition of the C language allows separate compilation (it defines “translation units” which can be translated independently) but does not define linking between different implementations of C.

Comment: @Gilles , OK so I suppose that rules it out then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111626/discussion-between-polcott-and-gilles-so-stop-being-evil).

Comment: "This means that there is a finite maximum number of addressable objects."
I would argue this is actually wrong.
As DR 260 points out, at https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_260.htm : "If two objects have identical bit-pattern representations and their types are the same they may still compare as unequal", and "[Implementations] may also treat pointers based on different origins as distinct even though they are bitwise identical.", which implies an implementation could store an infinite amount of information on each pointer and use that when derefencing/comparing pointers.

Comment: @GabrielRavier That DR is only about objects with indeterminate values (the examples are all about pointer objects which neither point inside-or-just-after an object nor are null). A valid pointer can be `memcpy`'d to an `unsigned char[]` and back, so the bit-pattern representation has to contain enough information to distinguish it from all other value pointers.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Hmmm, that makes sense. Though the abstract machine could associate the extra information with each of the bytes of the pointer such that recreating the pointer with each corresponding byte works out to the same one, I guess that means if you swap bytes from pointers with identical bit-pattern representations it won't work out correctly, and I'm pretty sure doing so is valid unless one tries to argue that integers have provenance (which would be madness)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' "If it runs out of memory, just move it to a bigger computer." But that is like someone saying, "My car's engine is a perpetual motion machine, but of course I have to put another gallon of gas in every 20 miles or so. So in theory it's a perpetual motion machine." But in the real world every machine will have a practical limit. A language specification, however elegant - as languages  like Lisp and SML are - can't circumvent corporeal existence.

Comment: @HankIgoe This metaphor doesn't work. An engine that consumes gas is not a perpetual motion machine, even in theory. A better metaphor would be: I can drive from New York to Los Angeles in my car, even though it has a limited fuel tank. If it runs out of fuel, just add more.

Answer (score 14):

C99's addition of `va_copy` to the variadic argument API may give us a back door to Turing-completeness. Since it becomes possible to iterate through a variadic arguments list more than once in a function other than the one that originally received the arguments, `va_args` can be used to implement a pointerless pointer.

Of course, a real implementation of the variadic argument API is probably going to have a pointer somewhere, but in our abstract machine it can be implemented using magic instead.

Here's a demo implementing a 2-stack pushdown automaton with arbitrary transition rules:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
typedef struct { va_list va; } wrapped_stack; // Struct wrapper needed if va_list is an array type.
#define NUM_SYMBOLS /* ... */
#define NUM_STATES /* ... */
typedef enum { NOP, POP1, POP2, PUSH1, PUSH2 } operation_type;
typedef struct { int next_state; operation_type optype; int opsymbol; } transition;
transition transition_table[NUM_STATES][NUM_SYMBOLS][NUM_SYMBOLS] = { /* ... */ };

void step(int state, va_list stack1, va_list stack2);
void push1(va_list stack2, int next_state, ...) {
    va_list stack1;
    va_start(stack1, next_state);
    step(next_state, stack1, stack2);
}
void push2(va_list stack1, int next_state, ...) {
    va_list stack2;
    va_start(stack2, next_state);
    step(next_state, stack1, stack2);
}
void step(int state, va_list stack1, va_list stack2) {
    va_list stack1_copy, stack2_copy;
    va_copy(stack1_copy, stack1); va_copy(stack2_copy, stack2);
    int symbol1 = va_arg(stack1_copy, int), symbol2 = va_arg(stack2_copy, int);
    transition tr = transition_table[state][symbol1][symbol2];
    wrapped_stack ws;
    switch(tr.optype) {
        case NOP: step(tr.next_state, stack1, stack2);
        // Note: attempting to pop the stack's bottom value results in undefined behavior.
        case POP1: ws = va_arg(stack1_copy, wrapped_stack); step(tr.next_state, ws.va, stack2);
        case POP2: ws = va_arg(stack2_copy, wrapped_stack); step(tr.next_state, stack1, ws.va);
        case PUSH1: va_copy(ws.va, stack1); push1(stack2, tr.next_state, tr.opsymbol, ws);
        case PUSH2: va_copy(ws.va, stack2); push2(stack1, tr.next_state, tr.opsymbol, ws);
    }
}
void start_helper1(va_list stack1, int dummy, ...) {
    va_list stack2;
    va_start(stack2, dummy);
    step(0, stack1, stack2);
}
void start_helper0(int dummy, ...) {
    va_list stack1;
    va_start(stack1, dummy);
    start_helper1(stack1, 0, 0);
}
// Begin execution in state 0 with each stack initialized to {0}
void start() {
    start_helper0(0, 0);
}
```

Note: If `va_list` is an array type, then there are actually hidden pointer parameters to the functions. So it would probably be better to change the types of all `va_list` arguments to `wrapped_stack`.

Comment: This might work. A possible concern is that it relies on allocating an unbounded number of automatic `va_list` variables `stack`. These variables must have an address `&stack`, and we can only have a bounded number of these. This requirement could be circumvented by declaring every local variable `register`, maybe?

Comment: @chi AIUI a variable is not required to have an address unless someone tries to take the address. Also, it's illegal to declare the argument immediately preceding the ellipsis `register`.

Comment: By the same logic, shouldn't an `int` be not required to have a bound unless someone uses the bound or `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @chi Not at all. The standard defines as part of the abstract semantics that an `int` has a value between some finite bounds `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`. And if the value of an `int` overflows those bound, undefined behavior occurs. On the other hand, the standard intentionally does not require that all objects be physically present in memory at a particular address, as this permits optimizations such as storing the object in a register, storing only part of the object, representing it differently than the standard layout, or omitting it altogether if it is not needed.

Comment: Doesn't work: the size of a struct must <= SIZE_T_MAX; which in turn means there are only 1<<SIZE_T_MAX possible invocations of step before it blows up. All types are blittable in C which means you could write a va_list to a file, discard the original, read it back again and it's still valid provided whatever it referenced is still in scope.

Comment: @Joshua As pointed out by @chi in the first comment, the game is up if you take the address of a variable (by, for example, passing it to `memcpy`). But if we avoid doing operations which force a standard violation to be exposed, then perhaps the implementation can cooperate with our aspirations to Turing-completeness.

Answer (score 3):

### Nonstandard arithmetic, maybe?

So, it seems that the issue is the finite size of `sizeof(t)`. However, I think I know a work around.

As far as I know, C does not require an implementation to use the standard integers for its integer type. Therefore, we could use a [non-standard model of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic). Then, we would set `sizeof(t)` to some nonstandard number, and now we will never reach it in a finite number of steps. Therefore, the length of the Turing machines tape will always be less than the "maximum", since the maximum is literally impossible to reach. `sizeof(t)` simply is not a number in the regular sense of the word.

This is one technicality of course: [Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem). It states that the only computable model of Peano arithmetic is the standard one, which obviously would not do. However, as far as I know, C does not require implementations to use data types that satisfy the Peano axioms, nor does it require the implementation to be computable, so this should not be an issue.

What should happen if you try to output a nonstandard integer? Well, you can represent any nonstandard integer using a nonstandard string, so just stream digits from the front of that string.

Comment: What would an implementation look like?

Comment: @reinierpost I am guessing it would represent data using some countable nonstandard model of PA. It would compute arithmetical operations using a [PA degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA_degree). I think any such model should provide a valid C implementation.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. `sizeof(t)` is itself a value of type `size_t`, so it is a natural integer between 0 and `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @Gilles SIZE_MAX would be a nonstandard natural as well then.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Note that you'd also need e.g. intptr_t / uintptr_t / ptrdiff_t / intmax_t / uintmax_t to be nonstandard. In C++ this would run afoul of forward progress guarantees... not sure about C.

Comment: @TLW I guess the only way to find out is to try to write an implementation based on this, lol. It would need to take a PA degree as input probably.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, but for an unexpected reason.

I believe the above comments are correct — given `size_t` is bounded, you cannot represent a turing machine with unbounded states by using C *as intended*.  However, we can use C in a way which completely circumvents the `size_t` issue — using only the C preprocessor.

I will not go over the whole proof here — [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526117) explains it best.  Essentially, using deferred expressions it is possible to create recursively expanding macros that expand **forever.**  In this way, the depth of the recursion becomes limited only to the number of scans which the machine executes — this is a physical limitation, but in theory the machine could scan forever.  The answer also explains how logical operations can be constructed.

So in conclusion: yes, C is turing-complete, but you have to totally misuse the preprocessor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136798 argues that the technique in that answer is does not yield Turing-completeness.  Do you have a rebuttal to that argument?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, a strong limitation is that the addressable space (via the pointer size) is finite, and this is unrecoverable.

One could advocate that memory can be "swapped to disk", but at some point the address information will itself exceed the addressable size.

Comment: Isn't this the main point of the accepted answer? I don't think it adds anything new to the answers of this 2016 question.

Comment: @chi: no, the accepted answer doesn't mention swapping to external memory, which might be believed to be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a language quite similar to C, where it is allowed to change sizeof, for example by assigning

```
sizeof(int) = 20;
sizeof(void*) += 4;
```

etc. That would be Turing complete. As your requirements go up, you would just modify sizeof(void*) to be sufficiently large, same with sizeof(size_t), and then you can use realloc to make your arrays bigger.

Comment: Wouldn't changing type sizes have to invalidate all existing structs, and arrays of pointers, at least?  Or I guess this hypothetical C environment could be "managed" and adjust things to still point to the right places after growing structs?  Note that changing the size of `void*` necessarily changes `(char*)&arr[10] - (char*)&arr[0]` for an array of `void*`.  But possibly you could define rules for how this works and force code to deal with the potentially massive inconvenience.  I guess if opaque things like FILE* become fully abstract, changing their internals doesn't matter?

Answer (score -1):

Removable media allows us to circumvent the unbounded memory problem. Perhaps people will think this is an abuse, but I think it's OK and essentially unavoidable anyway.

Fix any implementation of a universal Turing machine. For the tape, we use removable media. When the head runs off the end or beginning of the current disc, the machine prompts the user to insert the next or previous one. We can either use a special marker to denote the left end of the simulated tape, or have a tape that's unbounded in both directions.

The key point here is that everything the C program must do is finite. The computer only needs enough memory to simulate the automaton, and `size_t` only needs to be big enough to allow addressing that (actually rather small) amount of memory and on the discs, which can be of any fixed finite size. Since the user is only prompted to insert the next or previous disc, we don't need unboundedly large integers to say "Please insert disc number 123456..."

I suppose the principal objection is likely to be to the involvement of the user but that seems to be unavoidable in any implementation, because there seems to be no other way of implementing unbounded memory.

Comment: I'd argue that, unless the C definition requires such unbounded external storage, then this can not be accepted as a proof of Turing completeness. (ISO 9899 does not require that, of course, being written for the real-world engineering.) What concerns me is that, if we accept this, by a similar reasoning we might claim that DFAs are Turing complete, since they could be used to drive a head over a tape (the external storage).

Comment: @chi I don't see how the DFA argument follows. The whole point of a DFA is that it only has read access to storage. If you allow it to "drive a head over a tape", isn't that exactly a Turing machine?

Comment: Indeed, I'm nitpicking a bit here. The point is: why is it OK to add a "tape" to C, let C simulate a DFA, and use this fact to claim that C is Turing complete, when we can't do the same to DFAs? If C has no way to implement unbounded memory on its own, then it should not be considered Turing complete. (I'd still call it "morally" Turing complete, at least, since the bounds are so large that in practice they do not matter in most cases) I think that to definitively settle the matter, one would need a rigorous formal spec of C (the ISO standard does not suffice)

Comment: @chi It's OK because C includes file I/O routines. DFAs don't.

Comment: C does not completely specify what these routines do -- most of their semantics is implementation defined. A C implementation is not required to store the file contents, for instance, I think it can behave as if every file was "/dev/null", so to speak. It is also not required to store an unbounded amount of data. I'd say that your argument is correct, when considering what the vast majority of C implementations do, and generalizing that behaviour to an ideal machine. If we strictly rely on the C definition, only, forgetting the practice, I don't think it holds.

Comment: @chi OK, those are fair points. I guess the direction I'm going in is that an ordinary C implementation on an ordinary computer can simulate a Turing machine, without needing to mess around with things like `size_t`.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - This seems to be "C + an external Turing-complete system is Turing-complete", which is somewhat less interesting. (External system being Turing complete? FSM? Yes, as given by it being able to follow the user prompts. Unbounded tape storage? Yes, as stated in the solution.)

Comment: @TLW What “external Turing-complete system” are you referring to? The machine’s operator just inserts the next or previous disc from the stack on request.  How is that Turing-complete?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - The operator is following a finite state machine, and has access to an infinite tape. Swap out the FSM of 'wait for prompt, remove disk and put it in the next or previous stack, pick next or previous disk, deal with potentially running off of the tape, insert disk' with one describing a simple UTM directly. Remember that UTMs can be surprisingly simple - you can run an UTM with 4 states and 6 symbols, for instance. 6 symbols is doable purely via orientation.

Comment: @TLW Sorry, I’m not seeing your point. My answer explicitly says that the C program implements a universal Turing machine. The operator is not doing any computation so the concept of Turing-completeness doesn’t apply to them. They’re just loading the discs.

Comment: You don't need removable media, just an unbounded `/dev/tape` that supports relative seeks.  Then you have `fread`, `fwrite`, and `fseek(fp, long_rel_offset, SEEK_CUR)`.  (fseek with SEEK_SET or SEEK_END absolute seeks could return `-1` and perhaps even set errno=EIO or errno=ESPIPE.  And fgetpos / fsetpos would always produce garbage or fail on this file: `fpos_t` is an opaque type anyway, not guaranteed meaningful.  `ftell` returns a long but I think it's ok if it simply errors on some types of files, like probably a tty in real systems.)

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn’t that computers, being limited by the real world, cannot implement a Turing-complete machine. The problem in this question here is that the C language itself doesn’t allow it.

The C language could easily be changed to be Turing complete.  Adding an integer type of unlimited size that can be used in malloc() and in pointer arithmetic would have solved the problem. In practice it wouldn’t make any difference, since we can’t even build a computer where 64 bit pointer sizes are the limit.

Answer (score -3):

In practice, these restrictions are irrelevant to Turing completeness.  The real requirement is to allow the tape to be arbitrary long, not infinite.  That would create a halting problem of a different kind (how does the universe "compute" the tape?)

It's as bogus as saying "Python isn't Turing complete because you can't make a list infinitely large".

[Edit: thanks to Mr. Whitledge for clarifying how to edit.]

Comment: I don't think this answers the quesiton.  The question already anticipated this answer, and explained why it isn't valid: "although the C standard allows for size_t to be arbitrarily large, it must be fixed at some length, and no matter what length it is fixed at it is still finite".  Do you have any response to that argument?  I don't think we can count the question as answered unless the answer explains why that argument is wrong (or right).

Comment: At any given time, a value of type `size_t` is finite. The problem is that you can't establish a bound for `size_t` that's valid throughout the computation: for any bound, a program might overflow it. But the C language states that there exists a bound for `size_t`: on a given implementation, it can only grow up to `sizeof(size_t)` bytes. Also, [be nice](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Saying that people who criticize you “can't think on their own” is rude.

Comment: This is the correct answer. A Turning machine does not require an infinite tape, it requires an "arbitrarily long" tape. That is, you may assume that the tape is as long as it needs to be to complete the computation. You may also assume that your computer has as much memory as it needs. An infinite tape is absolutely not required, because any computation that halts in finite time cannot possibly use an infinite amount of tape.

Comment: What this answer shows is that for each TM you can write a C implementation with sufficient pointer length to simulate it. It however isn't possible to write *one* C implementation that can simulate *any* TM. So the specification prohibits that any particular implementation is T-complete. It isn't T-complete itself either, because pointer length is fixed.

Comment: But that's just saying that you can't make a Turing machine ANYWHERE:  because you'll always be limited by address size or some equivalent restriction (how many skips, etc.).

Comment: Pointer length isn't fixed: I think you can have different object files compiled with different pointer lengths.

Comment: This is another correct answer which is hardly visible due to the incapacity of most individuals in this community. Meanwhile, the accepted answer is false and its comment section is guarded by moderators deleting critical comments. Bye bye, cs.stackexchange.

Comment: This answer is actually right.

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge - the problem is that size_t is observable, whereas unused portions of a Turing machine's tape are not. Consider a hypothetical compiler that picked a "large enough" value of size_t. Now consider what happens when you compile and run `printf("%zu", SIZE_MAX); run_utm_on_stdin();`.

Comment: @reinierpost - "Pointer length isn't fixed". It is actually, at least within a single compile by C89 spec. (The as-if rule applies, so an implementation could mix pointer sizes "under-the-hood", but it can't let the fact it's doing so affect the behavior of a standard-compliant program, so it's a moot point.)

Comment: "The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.". Note the "constant" part there.

Comment: @TLW: Yes, but C has separate compilation, and dynamic linking. However, it can be argued that those are not features of the C language itself.

Answer (score -3):

## Choose `size_t` to be infinitely large

You could choose `size_t` to be infinitely large.  Naturally, it is impossible to realize such an implementation.  But that's no surprise, given the finite nature of the world we live in.

## Practical Implications

But even if it were possible to realize such an implementation, there would be practical issues.  Consider the following C statement:

```
printf("%zu\n",SIZE_MAX);
```

This prints a decimal representation of `SIZE_MAX` to standard out.  Presumably, `SIZE_MAX` is $O(2^{size\_t})$.  So if `size_t` is infinitely large, `SIZE_MAX` is also infinitely large.  The only way I know to print a decimal form of an infinitely large number is to produce an infinite stream of decimal digits.  This means that `printf` will not terminate in some cases.

Fortunately, for our theoretical purposes, I could not find any requirement in the specification that guarantees `printf` will terminate for all inputs.  So, as far as I am aware, we do not violate the C specification here.

## On Computational Completeness

It still remains to *prove* that our theoretical implementation is [Turing Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).  We can show this by implementing "any single-taped Turing Machine".

Most of us have probably implemented a Turing Machine as a school project.  I won't give the details of a specific implementation, but here's a commonly used strategy:

- The number of states, number of symbols, and state transition table are fixed for any given machine.  So we can represent states and symbols as numbers, and the state transition table as a 2-dimensional array.
- The tape can be represented as a linked list.  We can either use a single double-linked list, or two single-linked lists (one for each direction from the current position).

Now let's see what's required to realize such an implementation:

- The ability to represent some fixed, but arbitrarily large, set of numbers.  In order to represent any arbitrary number, we choose `MAX_INT` to be infinite as well.  (Alternatively, we could use other objects to represent states and symbols.)
- The ability to construct an arbitrarily large linked list for our tape.  Once again, there is no finite limit on the size.  This means we cannot construct this list up-front, as we would spend forever just to construct our tape.  But, we can construct this list incrementally if we use dynamic memory allocation.  We can use `malloc`, but there's a little more we must consider:

  - The C specification allows `malloc` to fail if, e.g., available memory has been exhausted.  So our implementation is only truly universal if `malloc` never fails.
  - However, if our implementation is run on a machine with infinite memory, then there is no need for `malloc` to fail.  Without violating the C standard, our implementation will guarantee that `malloc` will never fail.
- The ability to dereference pointers, lookup array elements, and access the members of a linked list node.

So the above list is what is necessary to implement a Turing Machine in our hypothetical C implementation.  These features must terminate.  Anything else, however, may be allowed to not terminate (unless required by the standard).  This includes arithmetic, IO, etc.

Comment: What would `printf("%zu\n",SIZE_MAX);` print on such an implementation?

Comment: @Ruslan, such an implementation is impossible, just like it's impossible to implement a Turing machine.  But if such an implementation were possible, I imagine it would print some decimal representation of an infinitely large number -- presumably, an infinite stream of decimal digits.

Comment: @NathanDavis It's possible to implement a Turing machine. The trick is that you don't need to build an infinite tape — you just build the used portion of the tape incrementally as needed.

Comment: @Gilles: In this finite universe in which we are living, it is is impossible to implement a Turing machine.

Comment: @Gilles, formal definitions aside, that argument seems suspiciously close to the OPs original objection regarding `size_t`.  You could incrementally increase `size_t` as well by suspending the machine, saving its state, building a new machine with an increased `size_t`, restoring the state, and resuming execution on the new machine.

Comment: @NathanDavis But if you do that, then you've changed `sizeof(size_t)` (or `CHAR_BITS`). You can't resume from the new state, you have to start again, but the execution of the program may be different now that those constants are different

Comment: @Gilles, I don't know why you'd have to start over.  You could certainly pad the words of the saved state when you resume to adjust for the new word size.  And you can certainly write a C program simulating a Turing Machine that does not rely on `sizeof(size_t)`, `CHAR_BITS`, or anything of that nature.  But, even if you did have to restart, you would only need to repeat a finite number of steps to reach the previous point.

Comment: @NathanDavis Then you wouldn't have an implementation of the C language, you'd have an implementation of the subset of the C language consisting of programs whose behavior does not depend on `sizeof(size_t)`. Not only that, but if you add up all the things that change (`sizeof(ssize_t)`, `sizeof(void*)`, etc.) you might not end up with a Turing-complete language anymore (I don't know if you do but it isn't obvious).

Comment: @Gilles, huh?  Are you saying there exists some finite `sizeof(size_t)` for which it is theoretically impossible to implement the C specification?  I'm just saying that a particular C program simulating a Turing Machine need not rely on `sizeof(size_t)` (other than, perhaps, to check whether it is necessary to switch to a larger machine).  But that does not limit the implementation of C upon which that program is built.

Comment: @NathanDavis The issue is not whether it's possible to implement the C specification, but whether the resulting language is Turing-complete. Which was kind of the point of this thread. You would need to check not only that the program doesn't contain `sizeof(size_t)` but more generally that it behaves identically under the expanded C implementation — for example, `malloc` would need to return the same pointer values if the Turing machine simulator uses it, etc. Increasing `CHAR_BIT` may be a better bet.

Comment: @NathanDavis - That would work, if all operations were restartable. However, not all operations are. (For instance: output to stdout.)

Comment: @TLW, not sure what you mean by "that" (something in the question or in the comments?).  However, there's no requirement that a Turing machine simulation use `stdout`.  So perhaps the program we use to simulate a Turing machine would simply not use `stdout`.

Comment: @NathanDavis: From a Turing-machine-theoretical standpoint, every program would be restartable, and any C program that would hit size limits associated with `CHAR_BIT` would do so i finite time.  So perhaps an implementation which runs until a program terminates or hits the limits of `CHAR_BIT`, then restarts with `CHAR_BIT` being `1<<(CHAR_BIT-1)`, so if it `CHAR_BIT` starts out being 16 for the first pass, it would be 32768 for the second pass, about 1E9800 for the third pass, etc. so restarts really shouldn't hurt speed much.

Comment: C programs can use dynamic linking; the fragments linked together don't need to use the same `size_t`. So in principle, a C program can use arbitrarily high `size_t` values.  This doesn't buy you anything unless the memory being addressed can be arbitrarily extended as well, as NathanDavis remarked.

Comment: @reinierpost: I don't think that's true.  `sizeof(size_t)` is an implementation-defined constant, the same across all translation units.  (And in practice will be part of the ABI for struct layouts and so on).  `inline` allowing identical definitions of the same function in different TUs is one clear way that it's not ok for different TUs to actually have the same code do something different.  Like most simply `inline foo() { return sizeof(size_t); }` has to return the same thing when called from anywhere in the program.

Comment: ISO C doesn't define linking together code from different implementations so that's already a non-starter.  And real implementations don't define the behaviour of linking together object files / libraries compiled for incompatible ABIs.  It usually breaks in real life when asm was generated with different struct layouts.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: OK, if linking is defined in the C standard and requires all units to have been compiled with the same `size_t`, then that is out.

Comment: @reinierpost: Not in those exact words, but yes a program can consist of multiple translation units.  I don't remember if there's *explicit* language requiring implementation-defined constants like `sizeof(size_t)` to actually be constant, but it's at least implied that they're constant across every translation unit.  And yes, the standard is written as a single C implementation handling every TU o a program; using a common ABI to enable linking between compilers is an implementation-defined feature. As Gilles' answer explains, agreeing on constants/layout = a C implementation in standardese.

Answer (score -3):

The problem here is that you're artificially limiting the set of C programs to just the ones that use pointers (and size_t, intptr_t, what have you), but that's not necessary. If you're forced to use only the standard library, then "no" is *kinda* correct like in the accepted answer, but the **semantics** of C are indeed Turing complete.

Say you have a Real Turing Machine (TM) and it provides a library for pushing and popping from two stacks of unbounded size, and (for thoroughness) lets also say that they just compile to push and pop assembler instructions. Now your C program can push and pop infinitely to two stacks, unrestrained by the semantics of C. Et voila, Turing completeness.

This is not the only way we can show that C is Turing complete, and it turns out that this is not a high bar to meet for programming languages. The real challenge is in constructing a language that is *not* turing complete (e.g. SQL), and giving a proof for it.

Note: Other answers seem to suggest that Turing completeness requires arbitrary memory access, but that's simply not true. A push-down automaton with two unbounded stacks is sufficient, hence the scenario above.

Comment: C plus a library with unbounded push and pop is Turing-complete. Sure. But the question was about C, not C plus a library that provides whatever bits might be missing from C. You've shown that it's possible to _give access_ to a PDA in C, not that it's possible to _implement_ a PDA in C.

Comment: The library doesn't give access to a PDA. It gives access to stacks. The question specifically asks about the semantics of C, and calling functions to access an unbounded stack is just as semantically valid as using a pointer to access RAM. You might as well argue that C doesn't let you implement RAM, but only gain access to it. The distinction is meaningless.

Answer (score -3):

**Mapping "C" to a Turing equivalent abstract model of computation**

C as it currently exists is not Turing complete because C inherently requires some fixed pointer size. We can however map a C like language to an abstract model of computation that is Turing complete.

The basic syntax and semantics of C could be mapped to an abstract model of computation that is Turing equivalent. The [RASP model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_stored-program_machine)  is a model that "C" can be mapped to.

A variation of the RASP model is shown below that the x86/x64 language maps to. Since it is already known that "C" maps to the x86/x64 concrete models of computation we know that "C" maps to the following abstract model:

```
Instruction
     : INTEGER ":" OPCODE                     // Address:Opcode 
     | INTEGER ":" OPCODE INTEGER             // Address:Opcode Operand 
     | INTEGER ":" OPCODE INTEGER "," INTEGER // Address:Opcode Operand, Operand
HEXDIGIT [a-fA-F0-9]
INTEGER  {HEXDIGIT}+ 
OPCODE   HEXDIGIT{4} 
// OPCODE distinguishes between INTEGER literal and machine address operand.
// OPCODE INTEGER is space delimited.
```

**Mapping the C language to the above abstract model of computation would enable the C language to become equivalent to a Turing machine.**

Because the x86/x64 language maps to the above abstract model this also provides the basis for recognizing the subset of Turing equivalent x86/x64/C computations. As long as the required pointer size is no larger than the pointer size that is available the computation is Turing equivalent on finite hardware.

Turing equivalent computations derive equivalent output or fail to halt on equivalent input between the concrete machine and its Turing machine equivalent.

Comment: Being able to map A to a subset of B does not imply that A is as powerful as B. You can map DFAs to a subset of Turing machines; that does not imply that DFAs are as powerful as Turing machines.

Comment: Or do you know a way around the problems with size_t / etc as discussed in other answers? Without a workaround here size_t can only address a finite subset of a RASP machine's ram.

Comment: @TLW it is common knowledge that most computing languages are Turing equivalent except for unbounded memory access.

Comment: @TLW language features such as x64 RIP relative addressing provide for linked lists of unbounded length.

Comment: "most computing languages are Turing equivalent except for unbounded memory access" is about as true as "most DFAs are Turing equivalent except for unbounded memory access".

Comment: "x64 RIP relative addressing" is not part of the C99 standard, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @TLW It is a part of the Intel 64 bit processor architecture. The C programming language could be mapped to this architecture.

Comment: You can map DFAs to a subset of the Intel 64 bit processor architecture too; that does not mean that DFAs are Turing-complete.

Comment: @TLW This will have to be my last reply to you or SE will cut off all comments. As I said most any conventional programming languages C, Fortran, COBOL, C++ et cetera are Turing equivalent except for the unlimited memory requirement.

Comment: I believe my previous comment already addressed that. By that same logic, "most DFAs are Turing equivalent except for the unlimited memory requirement".

Comment: @TLW **No you are wrong:** [Chomsky_hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)

Comment: **Precisely**. It is wrong to state that "most computing languages are Turing equivalent except for unbounded memory access", just as it is wrong to state most DFAs are Turing equivalent except for unbounded memory access.

Comment: Sorry, sarcasm sometimes doesn't come over well on the internet. Read "is about as true as" from my previous comment as "is obviously *not* true, because the same logic would also prove the following thing that is obviously false: ".

Comment: @TLW I opened up this thread on Google Groups [**comp.theory**](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.theory/c/3S-zl2lhDzU)  We can talk this all the way through there.

Answer (score -4):

The main argument here was that the size of the size_t is finite, although can be infinitely large.

There is a workaround for it, though I am not sure if this coincides with ISO C.

Assume you have a machine with infinite memory. Thus you are not bounded for pointer size. You still have your size_t type. If you ask me what is sizeof(size_t) the answer will be just sizeof(size_t). If you ask if it is greater than 100 for example the answer is yes. If you ask what is sizeof(size_t) / 2 as you could guess the answer is still sizeof(size_t). If you want to print it we can agree on some output. The difference of these two can be NaN and so on.

The summary is that relaxing the condition for size_t have finite size won't break any programs already existing.

P.S. Allocating memory sizeof(size_t) is still possible, you need only countable size, so let's say you take all evens (or similar trick).

Comment: "The difference of these two can be NaN". No it cannot be. There is no such thing as a NaN of integer type in C.

Comment: According to the standard, `sizeof` has to return a `size_t`. So you have to choose some particular value.

Comment: My reasoning is similar. Instead I make sizeof(size_t) whatever finite size that is large enough for the current computation. This works for all computations requiring a finite amount of memory. Counting to infinity and storing the value of each increment is not on of these computations.

Comment: @polcott - what would `printf("%zu\n",sizeof(size_t));` print on such an implementation?

Comment: @TLW The size_t that I am referring to is a variable and not the conventional fixed constant.

Comment: Then it is an interesting language; it is not standard C. The C89 spec, for instance, requires that `SIZE_MAX` be a constant expression. Different implementations may choose different values, but it must be constant within a single compile.

Comment: 7.18.3 Limits of other integer types: "Each instance of these macros shall be replaced by a constant expression [...] limit of size_t SIZE_MAX"